# Update View/Model after "reset" in ember

Tags: ember.js, data-binding, ember-data

In the app you can update the style and reset it. The reset is just a POST HTTP Request to `<url>/style/reset`. I've overwritten the destroyRecord in the model already, but my main problem is if I "delete" the record, I have to update the view and set the resetted style.

I thought the easiest way would be to transition through the route again, but transitionToRoute in the controller doesn't call the "model" in the route again.

Route:

```
App.SystemStyleRoute = App.ApplicationRoute.extend
   model: (params) ->
     @store.find "systemStyle"
```

In The Controller:

```
reset: ->
  @get('model').destroyRecord()

  # route back to the page to see the resetted style
  @transitionToRoute "system.style"
```

Comment: if you want to reload from adapter you should call @get('model').reload() after 'destroyRecord()'

Comment: @get('model').destroyRecord().then(=>
      @get('model').reload()
    )

I get: Attempted to handle event `reloadRecord` on <App.SystemStyle:ember574:1> while in state root.deleted.saved

Comment: @get('model').destroyRecord().then(=> @set('model', @store.find('systemStyle')) would be my next guss

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Yeah, this should work, altough it doesn't look like a clean way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this hacky approach:

```
@get('model').destroyRecord().then(=> @store.find('systemStyle').then( (obj) => @set 'model', obj ) )
```

Edit: Fix by Nicolas.

Comment: again, there is a problem, when I want to re-save this record I get:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Found the problem: I only get a promise back, so the code should be 
@get('model').destroyRecord().then(=> 
  @store.find('systemStyle').then( (obj) =>
   @set 'model', obj
  )
)